# Java: Threading in Shutdown Hook

Tags: java, multithreading, shutdown, shutdown-hook

I have a manager class that allows sub-modules to register a shutdown-hook using `Runnable`.

```
public class ApplicationManager() {
    private final List<Runnable> shutdownHooks;

    private ApplicationManager() {
        // Other stuff

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            if (shutdownHooks != null && !shutdownHooks.isEmpty()) {
                shutdownHooks.parallelStream()
                             .forEach(Runnable::run);
            }
        }));
    }

    // Other singleton stuff

    public void registerShutdownHook(final Runnable hook) {
        if (hook != null) {
            this.shutdownHooks.add(hook);
        }
    }

    public void resetApplication() {
        // Reset stuff

        shutdownHooks.parallelStream()
                     .forEach(Runnable::run);
        shutdownHooks.clear();
    }
}
```

The reason why this class does not accept `Thread` instances in `registerShutdownHook()` was mainly to reduce the complexity for the caller (so they do not need to wrap in an instance of `Thread`).

The application can be resetted, and I want to clean up the application by executing all the shutdown hooks. Although, I could wrap each `Runnable` with a `Thread`, register all of them with `Runtime` during `registerShutdownHook()`, and remove them from `Runtime` when `resetApplication()` is called, but I thought it may be neater that I control what needs to run.

In order to speed things up during cleanup, I used `parallelStream()`. Now I'm wondering if that is a bad idea to (during shutdown hook):

1. Use the thread pool;
2. Alternatively, create more threads.

Anyone experienced enough to give an advice?

Comment: You might have some issues with parallel execution if some hooks depend on others and/or access shared variables without synchronization

Comment: @Ivan Other than that this shouldn't cause any problem?